# multiple table in SQL android studio

Tags: android-studio

i have create multiple table in sql as show by other developer and after am try to register the user the app unfortunate has stop.
here are some code in databasehelper

those are tables
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "StudentElectoralCommittees";

//Tables name
private static final String TABLE_USERS1 = "Admin";
private static final String TABLE_USERS2 = "StudentDetails";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY1 = "SRC_President/Chairperson";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY2 = "Vice_President/Vice_Chairperson";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY3 = "SecretaryGeneral";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY4 = "SRC_for_Finance";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY5 = "SRC_for_Information_and_Publicity";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY6 = "SRC_for_Academic_Affairs";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY7 = "SRC_for_Accommodations";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY8 = "SRC_for_Transportation";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY9 = "SRC_for_Sport_and_Culture ";
private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY10 = "SRC_for_Gender_and_Welfare";

int oldVersion=1;
```

the way i create table follow below`enter code here`
 //create insert method to insert data into the database
    public boolean insert (String FirstName, String SecondName, String Email, String Password) {

```
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //create content values
    ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
    values1.put("FirstName", FirstName);
    values1.put("SecondName", SecondName);
    values1.put("Email", Email);
    values1.put("Password", Password);

    //insert into database table
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_USERS1, null, values1);
    return true;
}
public boolean insert2 (String FullName, String StudentNumber, String Course, String Level) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //create content values
    ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
    values2.put("FullName", FullName);
    values2.put("StudentNumber", StudentNumber);
    values2.put("Course", Course);
    values2.put("Level", Level);

    //insert into database table
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_USERS2, null, values2);
    return true;
}
public boolean insert3 (String Cand_Name, String Counts){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values3 = new ContentValues();
    values3.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values3.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY1, null, values3);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values4 = new ContentValues();
    values4.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values4.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY2, null, values4);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values5 = new ContentValues();
    values5.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values5.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY3, null, values5);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values6 = new ContentValues();
    values6.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values6.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY4, null, values6);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values7 = new ContentValues();
    values7.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values7.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY5, null, values7);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values8 = new ContentValues();
    values8.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values8.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY6, null, values8);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values9 = new ContentValues();
    values9.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values9.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY7, null, values9);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values10 = new ContentValues();
    values10.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values10.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY8, null, values10);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values11 = new ContentValues();
    values11.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values11.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY9, null, values11);

    //create content values for categories
    ContentValues values12 = new ContentValues();
    values12.put("Cand_Name", Cand_Name);
    values12.put("Counts", Counts);

    //insert into categories tables
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_CATEGORY10, null, values12);
    return true;
}
//checking if the email existing
public Boolean chkemail (String Email){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Admin where Email=?", new String[]{Email});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) return false;
    else return true;

}
//checking if the Student number existing
public Boolean chkStudentNo (String StudentNumber){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Student where StudentNumber=?", new String[]{StudentNumber});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) return false;
    else return true;

}
```

}

Comment: Might also help if you provide details of the error you get when the app stops

Comment: Once i run it, it only says unfortunate the <app name> has stop